# Why Mozilla products install on regional language?

Tags: fedora, yum, kde

I'm running Fedora 27 KDE, and I've since added and deleted a regional language (now it's only US-EN in Regional settings). However, whenever I'm installing Mozilla products (Thunderbird, Filezilla) through Discover or yum, they come in the local language by default. Have not experienced that yet with other applications, such as LibreOffice, which launched in English after installation, even though I know it has my local language translation.

If Mozilla is deciding what version to ship based on my IP or mirror, is there a way to tell them to stop, and if there's something in my system deciding what language package to install, how can I change that?

Comment: Have you selected the correct language in your KDE settings? Most programs will use whatever language you have specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

even though regional language was removed, Region was still set to the local one, missed these settings before.